# $(x - i)^n$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n + 1$ form a basis of the space of the polynomials of degree $\leq n.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the polynomials $(x - i)^n$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n + 1$ form a basis of the space of the polynomials of degree $\leq  n.$

I'm a little confused on how to take care of the binomial expansion, which I need to get that they are linearly independent. And then the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

hint:we know B={$1,x,x^2,...,x^n$} is base of $P_n[X]$ ,|B|=n+1 we want prove B'={$(x - 1)^n,(x - 2)^n,(x - 3)^n,...,(x - n-1)^n$} because |B'|=n+1 thats enough to prove B' is linear  independent $$a_1(x - 1)^n+a_2(x - 2)^n+a_3(x - 3)^n,...,a_{n+1}(x - n-1)^n=0$$ by use of Newton polynomial we have  $$a_1b_1+a_2b_2x+...+a{}b{}x^n=0$$ a B is base of $P_n[X]$ then $a_ib_i=0$ such that $b_i\ge0$ easily conclude  $a
_i=0 $

Comment: @Babak Sorouh: hi your welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Linear independence of the polynomials is just nonsingularity of the matrix of coefficients of the polynomials. This matrix is a almost a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).